# How to put the link to the last created quiz in the email that will be sent to all users automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I could be able to let the web application sends automatic emails using Windows Task Scheduler. Now I want to put the link to last created quiz by admin in that email. **How to do that? Should I add any column in the Quiz table in the database?**

The table schema:

***Employee Table: Username, Name, Job, Email***

***Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description***

My code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("mail address");
        MailMessage msg = null;

        try
        {
            msg = new MailMessage("xxxx@gmail.com",
                "yyyy@gmail.com", "Message from PSSP System",
                "This email sent by the PSSP system");

             sc.Send(msg);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (msg != null)
            {
                msg.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to send an email to someone(maybe your customer), inside the email body, you want to have a link, when user click the link it will navigate user to your quiz through browser, is it right?

If the above assumption is right, you don't need to add a new column.

assume the asp.net page which you display quiz is quiz.aspx

http://www.XXXX.com/quiz.aspx?quizId=XXX

Just add the above link in your email body.

in quiz.aspx. you can get the quizId by request["quizId"],then read the related quiz from your database and display.